# How to properly use join query mysql InnoDB

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am creating my first php mysql web application and am not too familiar with how to use the sql JOIN. The following are the table layouts:

Table1:
PK saleid

Table 2:
PK stockid

Table 3:
PK saleFK
PK stockFK

I have created the relationships such that table3.saleFK is a foreign key of table1.saleid and table3.stockFK is a foreign key of table2.stockid. How would I write a join function to pull a related stockid in Table 2 of a single saleid in Table 1?

It's hard to put this in words, please let me know if you need further explanation. I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table3 t3
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON (t2.stockid = t3.stockid)
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON (t1.saleid = t3.saleid)
```

I think this is what you are asking. This should return all the data from Table 3 with the relevant data joined in from Table 1 and Table 2.

Comment: Will this return an array of all rows in table 2 that are linked to my pk in table 1 through table 3? Do I need a where table.saleid = ..?

Comment: Just tried it out and this is what I got as an error: Unknown column 'sale.saleid' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM (`vehicles`) INNER JOIN `vehicle_sale` ON `vehicle_sale`.`vehicleFK` = `vehicles`.`stockid` INNER JOIN `sales` ON `sales`.`saleid` = `vehicle_sale`.`saleFK` WHERE `sale`.`saleid` = '25744661'

Comment: Your table is `sales` but you put `sale.saleid`, you need `sales.saleid`

Comment: In response to your first question, this will return all field from `vehicles` with the `vehicle_sales` joined in and the `sales` joined in where the `saleid` = `25744661`. Without knowing the `one-to-one` or `one-to-many` or `many-to-one` relationships of your tables I cannot tell you if you actually might want to use `LEFT/RIGHT JOINS` instead. My query is assuming a `one-to-one` relationship in all cases.

Comment: You are correct. It was a stupid typing error on my part. Yes it was a one-to-one relationship. Thanks for your help @Leeish!